# Read .xlsm file using Apache POI get more cells in a row

Tags: apache-poi, xlsm

I use below code to read a .xlsm file:

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(input);
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

int firstRow = sheet.getFirstRowNum();
int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
for (int rownum = firstRow; rownum < lastRow; rownum++) {
    Row row = sheet.getRow(rownum);
    short firstCell = row.getFirstCellNum();
    short lastCell = row.getLastCellNum();
```

The code works well except at a specific row, there are only 7 cells show in MS Excel, but in the program I got 27 cells, most of them null, only the last few columns with data I couldn't see in MS Excel.

Is it due to the wrong format/data in the xlsm file(how to check if so?), or anything else?

Comment: The last cell encountered by [Row.getLastCellNum](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getLastCellNum--) definitely is stored in the cells of that row. See: "Note: cells which had content before and were set to empty later might still be counted as cells ...". To see it in Excel, select that cell there and have a look at the formular bar and the format of that cell. If there is someting in the formular bar or the format is special (not default), then the cell must be stored and so also is present.

Comment: @AxelRichter You are right, thanks for your help!